# Example with parameter curl -x php

Tags: php, curl

I have to make a curl request in php with these parameters, can you help me with an example, since I can't find anything similar

the link curl

```
curl -X GET "https://example.com/nms/api/v2.1/devices?withInterfaces=true&authorized=false&type=uisps&role=switch" -H "accept: application/json" -H "x-auth-token: wsedr4455-3345-es45-2345-4edeesssd"
```

Comment: Just use a converter such as https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Comment: I rolled back your update, since that makes it a totally different question and invalidates the answer and comment already given. Make a new post if you have an issue specifically with processing the data.  But first you should follow the link Markus gave below anyway, since it teaches you how to understand your data and then access different parts of it. Once you learn the principles it should be easy to get what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should transform it into [PHP curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init) syntax. It should work like this:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://example.com/nms/api/v2.1/devices?withInterfaces=true&authorized=false&type=uisps&role=switch');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'accept: application/json',
    'x-auth-token: wsedr4455-3345-es45-2345-4edeesssd'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The JSON incoming is in `$result`.

Comment: The example is perfect, how could I visualize the data?

Comment: Do you mean the result? You may echo it and see the JSON or transform it to a PHP array for further use. `print_r(json_decode($result));`

Comment: Indeed, with json_decode they are shown in an array, but I do not have much experience with this, I have tried to move through the data like this print_r(json_decode($result[0][1])); but it doesn't work well, and I need to dump the info to a database

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php